# Finite element method boundary estimate

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I just want to recall a formula. In finite element let $u$ be the exact solution, $u^h$ be the approximation. If $\Omega$ is the region, is there a formula $$||u-u^h||_{H^{\frac{1}{2}}(\Omega)}\leq h^{\frac{1}{2}}||u||_{H^1(\Omega)}$$